# PHP / MYSQL / RSS Feed loads all posts into one post

Tags: php, mysql, rss

When you pull the RSS feed it shows 1 post, but within that post, all the other posts show up. I have checked all of my closings, and have revised the code over and over again, but cannot see where the problem is. On certain RSS readers it just says error could not read feed.  But on others I have this issue.

Any direction will help.  Code below:

---

```
<?PHP

$host = "****";
$un = "****";
$pw = "****";
$db = "****";

$link = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw) or die(mysql_error());
if(!$link){ die("Could not connect to MARTHA GRAEFF - AROUND IN STYLE database: " . mysql_error()); }
$selectDB = mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$selectDB){ die ("Can't use MARTHA GRAEFF - AROUND IN STYLE database: " . mysql_error()); }

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
echo '<rss version="2.0">';
echo '<channel>';
echo '<title>TITLE OF THE FEED</title>';
echo '<description>BLOG DESCRIPTION</description>';
echo '<link>http://www.example.com</link>';

$get_articles = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `image`, `text`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%a, %e %b %Y') as `date` FROM `posts` WHERE `date` <= CURDATE() ORDER BY `added` DESC LIMIT 20";
$articles = mysql_query($get_articles);

while($a = mysql_fetch_array($articles)){
echo "<item>";
    echo "<title>" . $a['title'] . "</title>";
    echo "<description><![CDATA[";
        echo "<img src='http://www.example.com/images/db/thumb.php?src=" .     $a['image'] . "&w=650' width='650' alt='" . $a['title'] . "' /><br />";

        $pid = $a['id'];
        $q = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `post_id`='" . $pid . "' ORDER BY `added` ASC";
        $r = mysql_query($q);     
        while($i = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
            echo "<img src='http://www.example.com/images/db/thumb.php?src=" . $i['image'] . "&w=650' width='650' alt='" . $a['title'] . "' /><br />";
        }

        echo $a['text'];
    echo "]]></description>";
    echo "<link>http://www.example.com/post.php?id=" . $a['id'] . "</link>";
    echo "<pubDate>" . $a['date'] . " EST</pubDate>";
echo "</item>";
}
echo "</channel>";
echo "</rss>";  

?>
```

Comment: Can you give sample of the output?

Comment: Someone is bound to come along and be upset about this sooner or later, so let me spare them.  The `mysql_*` commands are deprecated.  Suggest you take a look at PDO when you get a chance: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Mike: http://www.aroundinstyle.com/rss.php

Comment: TUBAGUY Thank you I will look into it definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can uses objects whit [mysql_fetch_object()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)
while your sql query and foreach your while

```
$get_articles = "SELECT `id`, `title`, `image`, `text`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%a, %e %b %Y') as `date` FROM `posts` WHERE `date` <= CURDATE() ORDER BY `added` DESC LIMIT 20";
$articles = mysql_query($get_articles);

while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($articles)) {
        $array[$obj->id]['id'] = $obj->id;
        $array[$obj->id]['title'] = $obj->title;
        $array[$obj->id]['image'] = $obj->image;
        $array[$obj->id]['date'] = $obj->date;  
}
```

And the output:

```
foreach ($array as $k) {
echo "<item>";
   echo "<title>" . $k['title'] . "</title>";
   echo "<description>" . $k['image'] . "</description>";
   echo "<date>" . $k['description'] . "</date>"; 
echo "</item>";
}
```

It's an exemple, you must code your way